# TFS 2010 Build Server and Microsoft.Practices References

Tags: tfs, build-automation

I am busy trying to configure a build server for TFS2010. My project has references to Microsoft.practices. The build fails because it can't find these references on the build server - because I haven't installed the Microsoft.practices on the build server.

I was wondering if installing it on the build server is the best way to do it, or is there another way to add the 3rd party references when configuring the build server?

I know I can just install it, but I'm looking to follow best practices here.

Regards,
Byron Cobb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the referenced third party dlls in TFS within your project. Structured similar to:

```
/ProjectSolution
   /ProjectA
   /ProjectB
   /lib
      /3rdPartyLibA
      /3rdPartyLibB
```

Now edit your build definition, in the Workspace tab, in the Working folders section, make a reference to you /lib folder in your project. The build agent will retrieve the 3rd party libs and use it for compilation.

Comment: If your build cannot find the libraries, you can find at http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/02/09/Where-is-the-AdditionalReferencePath-in-TFS-2010.aspx how to specify the hint path.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to check-in third party assemblies in TFS. You can add an additional folder to your TFS with a fixed relative path to your project. Then add references from there. This way you don't need to install 3rd party assemblies in your build agents. Additionally you don't need to edit your build definition too.